# SystemVerilog: Sensitivity list of always_comb

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

It seems to me that `always_comb` is not sensitive to variables assigned in the block itself. For example, the following block:

```
always_comb begin
    a = b;
    b = c;
end
```

seems to be only sensitive to `c` (so whenever `c` changes, `b` gets the value of `c`, and `a` gets the *previous* value of `b`) in simulation. If I synthesize this, it works as expected (`a`, `b` and `c` always have the same value).

Is there any reason `always_comb`, which is supposed to simulate combinational logic, behaves "incorrectly" in simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because simulation does not do the same kind of data flow analysis that a synthesis tool does to know that `b` is just a temporary variable. The LRM was written thinking that you always write to variables before reading the same variable in the same block. An always_comb block should be written as if it were a function called whenever an input to the block changes. To have the block re-trigger can be very bad for performance.

The same style is used for a sequential always_ff block: a read before write within the same block is a flop, a write before read is a temporary variable.